# VBA code to hide a number of fixed discrete rows across a few worksheets

Tags: vba, excel

I'm for a solution to part of a macro I'm writing that will hide certain (fixed position) rows across a few different sheets. I currently have:

`Sheets(Sheet1).Range("5:20").EntireRow.Hidden = True`

To hide rows 5-20 in Sheet1. I also would like to hide (for arguements sake), row 6, row 21, and rows 35-38 in Sheet2 - I could do this by repeating the above line of code 3 more times; but am sure there's a better way of doing this, just as a learning exercise.

Any help much appreciated :)

Chris

Comment: Thanks guys - had no idea about unions! I'll do some studying.

Comment: Try: Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A6,A21,A35:A38").EntireRow.Hidden = True

Comment: OR:  Sheets("Sheet2").Range("6:6,21:21,35:38").Hidden = True

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Specify a `Union` of some ranges as follows

```
With Sheet1
    Union(.Range("1:5"), .Rows(7), .Range("A10"), .Cells(12, 1)).EntireRow.Hidden = True
End With
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is a try:

```
Sub hideMultiple()
    Dim r As Range
    Set r = Union(Range("A1"), Range("A3"))
    r.EntireRow.Hidden = True
End Sub
```

But you cannot `Union` range from several worksheets, so you would have to loop over each worksheet argument.

Answer (score 2):

This is a crude solution: no validation, no unhiding of existing hidden rows, no check that I have a sheet name as first parameter, etc.  But it demonstrates a technique that I often find useful.

I load an array with a string of parameters relevant to my current problem and code a simple loop to implement them.  Look up the sub and function declarations and read the section on ParamArrays for a variation on this approach.

```
Option Explicit
Sub HideColumns()

  Dim InxPL As Integer
  Dim ParamCrnt As String
  Dim ParamList() As Variant
  Dim SheetNameCrnt As String

  ParamList = Array("Sheet1", 1, "5:6", "Sheet2", 9, "27:35")

  SheetNameCrnt = ""

  For InxPL = LBound(ParamList) To UBound(ParamList)
    ParamCrnt = ParamList(InxPL)
    If InStr(ParamCrnt, ":") <> 0 Then
      ' Row range
      Sheets(SheetNameCrnt).Range(ParamCrnt).EntireRow.Hidden = True
    ElseIf IsNumeric(ParamCrnt) Then
      ' Single Row
      Sheets(SheetNameCrnt).Range(ParamCrnt & ":" & _
                                          ParamCrnt).EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Else
      ' Assume Sheet name
      SheetNameCrnt = ParamCrnt
    End If
  Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Tony, I'll definitely look into this :)

Comment: Welcome, I think an investigation will repay your time. Parameter driven code was very popular when I was young but seems to have fallen out of favour. Programming languages which compile to intermediate code are using this technique. With pre-validation, the performance can be very impressive.   Techniques go out of fashion.  I am not the world's greatest programmer but I have 45 years' worth of techniques to draw on.