# Hide Row Macro Taking Long Time to Run

Tags: vba, excel

Is there a way to make this code run faster? I am trying to hide rows that are blank across multiple worksheets.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub HideRows_Click()

Dim ws As Worksheet, c As Range

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    On Error Resume Next

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        Select Case ws.Name
        Case "Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3"
        'sheets to exclude
            'do nothing

        Case Else 'hide rows on these sheets
            For Each c In ws.Range("AJ16:AJ153,AJ157:AJ292")
                c.EntireRow.Hidden = c.Value = 0
            Next c
        End Select
    Next ws

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Turn off calculations and events.

Comment: This is an interesting line `c.EntireRow.Hidden = c.Value = 0`, what is it supposed to be doing?

Comment: @Marcucciboy2 `Range.Hidden` wants `TRUE/FALSE` so if c.Value <> 0 it returns `FALSE` and `TRUE` when it does.

Comment: @ScottCraner oh that's actually pretty clever...

Comment: You can union the ranges and hide them all together at once like so: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8740424/vba-code-to-hide-a-number-of-fixed-discrete-rows-across-a-few-worksheets. No need to loop at all!

Comment: @ScottCraner that settles it, i need to take a break from this for a bit haha

Comment: @Marcucciboy2 how would I change it so it's looping through the row instead of each cell? Thanks!

Comment: dont worry about that, I was mistaken :)

Comment: When you say `Macro Taking Long Time`, how long is it taking? Also, have a look at @ScottCraner first comment

Comment: @JvdV  I would think that one would need to loop to create the union.  But using union to hide all the rows at once is definitely quicker.

Comment: One more note, remove the `On Error Resume Next`, it will hide errors that need to be fixed instead of ignored.  there is a time and place to use it, but it should not be the default action.  only about 1% of code needs it.

Comment: Having set a `printArea` can dramatically slow down your code

Comment: Here's a good example of the code you can use to halt vba application events https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/200023/155816

Comment: @ScottCraner so it seems like the solution is to **1)** loop through range and union when empty **2)** hide unioned range - rather than to hide row by row

Comment: @Marcucciboy2 yup.

Comment: @ScottCraner, I overlooked that the range provided need to be searched for empty rows. So yes it will need one loop.

Comment: feels like improvement might be negligible, but thoughts on first grabbing the range as an array to loop through?

Comment: @Marcucciboy2 it can't hurt, just make sure you line up the row numbers properly, You will need two loops or put logic to skip the 3 rows not wanted in the test as you cannot load a single array with a disjointed range.

Comment: @ScottCraner dropped in the non-array solution below.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some of the changes made to your code with the intention of speeding it up:

- Turning off calculations, events, and status bar
- First grouping all values in `AJ` with no values via the `Union()` function and *then* calling `EntireRow.Hide` on that combined range

It was honestly pretty clean code to begin with!

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub HideRows_Click()

    With Application
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .DisplayStatusBar = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

    'On Error Resume Next

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In Worksheets

        Select Case ws.name
            Case "Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3" 'sheets to exclude
                'do nothing

            Case Else 'hide rows on these sheets
                Dim unioned As Range
                Set unioned = Nothing

                Dim c As Range
                For Each c In ws.Range("AJ16:AJ153,AJ157:AJ292")
                    If Len(c.Value2) = 0 Then
                        If unioned Is Nothing Then
                            Set unioned = c
                        Else
                            Set unioned = Union(unioned, c)
                        End If
                    End If
                Next c

                unioned.EntireRow.Hidden = True
        End Select

    Next ws

    With Application
        .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .DisplayStatusBar = True
        .EnableEvents = True
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: I didn't really feel like I was responsible for putting this together so I answered it as community wiki

Comment: thanks for the help! there's an issue though when i try to run the code with the line "set unioned = Union(unioned, c)

Comment: run time error '1004'. method 'union' of object'_global' failed

Comment: @tangkt try adding in "Application" : `Set unioned = Application.Union(unioned, c)`

Comment: @tangkt okay, it looks like the problem is actually that excel wants to be sure that both ranges you union are on the same sheet. So I have two ideas but I can’t test them at this moment as I’m “mobile”. **1)** try `set unioned = nothing` right after it is dimmed or **2)** see if just specifying the worksheet works like `Union(ws.unioned, c)`

Comment: didn't seem to work on my end. let me know if you get to try it and if it works for you. thanks again for the help!

Comment: @tangkt apologies that you got lost in the weekend, I hope you didn't give up on this! I was able to replicate your error and on my machine adding the `Set unioned = Nothing` worked. Could you try copying it from the edited version above and give it another try?